# Region in the XY plane over which the double integral is taken.

Tags: multivariable-calculus, multiple-integral

$$\int_{-1}^1\int_{1+x}^1\cos(x+y)e^{(y-x)}\,dy\,dx $$

I suppose the region is this:

$D=\{ (x,y) \in \Bbb R^2 \mid 1+x \le y \le 1$ $ \&$  $ -1\le x \le 1 \}$

But I am not able to understand the region as $x \gt 0  $   and   $    1+x \le y \le 1$ , this is not making sense.

If possible please  explain the region graphically.

Edit:

As in comments , i understood the above question.

Now i want to compute the integral using transformation $x +y = u$ and $y-x = v$.

So what is the corresponding region in $uv$ plane.

Please provide the solution to this integral using the transformation.

Comment: Maybe is it useful: https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=-1%3C%3Dx%3C%3D1%2C+1%2Bx%3C%3Dy%3C%3D1?

Comment: @АлександрПальма  if this is the region than instead of -1<x<1 , we could take -1<x<0

Comment: The inner integraml is a one variable integral with the parameter $x$. Who said that in  such an integral the upper bound should be greater than the lower bound?

Comment: @Bernard  please explain , i didn't get it.

Comment: When the lower bound is greater, the integral is the opposite of the integral the other way. For instance $ \int_2^1 f(t)\,\mathrm dt =-\int_1^2 f(t)\,\mathrm dt$, simply because the $\Delta t$, in the Riemann sums, have opposite signs. Is it clearer?

Comment: @Bernard yes. Then the region in xy plane is 1+x<y<1 , when -1<x <0, and 1<y<1+x , when 0<x<1   ?

Comment: Yes, I think so. Geometrically, it looks like a bow tie.